# Count before executing Worksheets(X).Columns(Y).Replace function

Tags: excel, replace, count, vba

I need to maintain a count of replacements made before implementing the Worksheets(...).Columns(...).Replace function using Excel VBA.

Can anyone guide me regarding code that I probably need to insert in *** below for counting the replacements that are about to occur in the next line of code? Thanks.

```
Function Value_Replace(TabName As String, ColumnTitle As String, val_Old As String, val_New As String)

    Dim MyColumn, CountReplacements As Long
    Dim MyColumnLetter As String

   MyColumn = WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnTitle, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(TabName).Range("1:1"), 0)

 'CountReplacements = ***?

Worksheets(TabName).Columns(MyColumnLetter).Replace _
    what:=val_Old, Replacement:=val_New, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

    Value_Replace = "Values " & CountReplacements & " in column " & MyColumnLetter & " updated!"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to store in the cell (eg `[A1]`) and the number of repetitions for each call to change to increment it. But it must be the end of all calculations to clear the cell that would be the next time you call this function, the function would not start incrementing the previous value.
Some will look like this:

```
[A1].value = [A1].value + 1
CountReplacements = [A1].value
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using COUNTIF with * Old_Str *? You don't need to count the actual replacements before they happen, just find out how many occurrences of Old_Str there are in your column within the contents of each cell before you start the replacement. Doing it on New_Str after you'd replaced it would be unwise unless you could guarantee there were no occurrences of New-Str before you executed the replacement .

```
CountReplacements = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(MyColumnLetter), "*" & val_Old & "*")
```

Give it a go and see

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. But this worked as well:

While Not ConsecutiveEmpty = 1

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow, 2).Value) Then
  ConsecutiveEmpty = ConsecutiveEmpty + 1
End If
LastRow = LastRow + 1
```

Wend

MyCount = 0

For i = 2 To LastRow

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, MyColumn).Value = val_Old Then
       MyCount = MyCount + 1
End If
```

Next